# How do I connect Blazor and SOAP API

Tags: c#, soap, blazor

I am very new to Blazor, and web dev, still learning the basics. I have a problem and i don't even know how to approach this. So I need to somehow connect up a soap API (DHL API to be exact) Here is the WSDL: `https://dhl24.com.pl/webapi2.`
The main thing this web site has to do is send packages through this API. Any ideas how to approach this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general in a .NET Core project you can add a Connected Service to your project

[image]

and choose Microsoft WCF Web Service Reference Provider.

[image]

That's the SOAP client stack for .NET, which has been ported to .NET Core.  I'm not sure if the VS tooling is the same for Blazor projects, but you should be able to  migrate the code from a .NET Core Console App if necessary.